# Why can't Steam's window be dragged or moved normally?

Tags: awesome, steam

Why Steam's windows can't be dragged using border and it's custom titlebar. Chromium works (almost) well with AwesomeWM, why Steam doesn't.

Comment: What UI library does steam use? Do other applications using the same UI library behave differently?

Comment: Screenshot? Including a normal window and a steam window?

Comment: This is also a problem in windowmaker. This has only been a bug for 3-4 years now. Get it together, Valve!

Answer (score 1):

If title bar and borders are custom, then that is the reason why you cannot drag them. Sounds like the window manager is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this problem also affects WindowMaker. Now, you can still move windows in wmaker, by holding ALT and dragging the window around. Including the steam client.

Is there some equivalent in Awesome?

It's still far from optimal, but it's a workaround.